# Semi-stable bundles as a heart of a t-structure

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, triangulated-categories, t-structure

Given an algebraic curve, the category of semi-stable vector bundles of fixed slope forms an abelian category see [here](http://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Elurie/205notes/Lecture20-HarderNarasimhan.pdf) page 2. This is surprising as the vector bundles themselves are not an abelian category. I was wondering whether there is a t-structure on let's say derived category of perfect complexes (maybe other derived category) that its heart gives the semi-stable bundles with fixed slope?

Comment: This is not literally an answer, but I think you should look into the notion of a Bridgeland stability condition. (Essentially, I am saying that the right derived-categorical notion to capture this situation is that of a stabillity condition, not of a t-structure.)

Comment: Literally an answer, but IMO less interesting: This is not possible because the classes in K-theory of such bundles (once you fix a slope) do not generate the K-group.